# Is there any difference between expectation value and average value in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, terminology, statistics

Is there any difference between expectation value and average value in quantum mechanics?
If there is no difference then why give them different names?

Comment: If I type "expectation value average value quantum mechanics" into a search engine, I get plenty of hits, which describe this.

Comment: Is there a difference in ordinary statistics? Why do you think quantum mechanics is special here?

Answer (score 3):

It is the same as for statistics and probability theory. Average applies to data. Expectation applies to predictions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @CharlesFrancis answer, but it is worth adding more terminology:  *expectation value* is *mathematical average/mean*, as opposed to the *ensemble average* or *sample average*. [See here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/631043/247642) for more.

**Remark:** the obligatory reference on statistics is [this crash course on statistics, from the Review of Particle Physics](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-statistics.pdf).